# how to bind to a container in order to iterate through blobs

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions

**Is it possible to iterate through the blobs inside of a container?**

Currently, I've added this attribute:

```
[Blob("%MyFunc:InputContainer%")]CloudBlobContainer inputContainer
```

However, I've not found any documentation on how to iterate through the the blobs inside of the `inputContainer`.

Comment: What about `CloudBlobContainer.ListBlobs` method ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblobcontainer.listblobs?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Storage_Blob_CloudBlobContainer_ListBlobs_System_String_System_Boolean_Microsoft_Azure_Storage_Blob_BlobListingDetails_Microsoft_Azure_Storage_Blob_BlobRequestOptions_Microsoft_Azure_Storage_OperationContext_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use ListBlobsSegmentedAsync to get blobs. I bind the container with this :`[Blob("firstcontainer")]CloudBlobContainer inputContainer`.

And with below code to get the blob list:

```
            BlobContinuationToken blobContinuationToken = null;
            var results = await inputContainer.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(null, blobContinuationToken);

            foreach (IListBlobItem item in results.Results)
            {
                log.LogInformation(item.Uri.Segments.Last());
            }
```

This is my test result, you could have a try. The blob name with `/` means it's a **directory**.

[image]

Hope this could help you.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the basic sample for this.

```html
#r "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage"

using System;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

public static void Run(Stream myBlob, CloudBlobContainer container,ILogger log)
{
log.LogInformation($"Container name: {container.Name}");
var blob= container.GetBlockBlobReference("Bill.pdf");
log.LogInformation($"Blob size: {blob.StreamWriteSizeInBytes}");
log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function processed {myBlob}");

}
```

**function.json**

```html
{
"bindings": [
{
"connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
"path": "samples-workitems/{name}",
"name": "myBlob",
"type": "blobTrigger",
"direction": "in"
},
{
"name": "container",
"type": "blob",
"path": "output-images",
"connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
"direction": "in"
}
],
"disabled": false
}
```

**function.Proj**

```html
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>  
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="WindowsAzure.Storage" Version="9.3.3"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="11.0.2"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `inputContainer.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync()`:

```
BlobResultSegment blobResultSegment = await container.ListBlobsSegmentedAsync(null);

// Iterate each blob
foreach (IListBlobItem item in blobResultSegment.Results)
{
    // cast item to CloudBlockBlob
    CloudBlockBlob blob = (CloudBlockBlob)item;
}
```